# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null

Tags: javascript, css, html, navigationbar

I am using HTML, CSS and JavaScript to create a web page with a sticky and responsive navigation bar. I created the responsive navigation bar and am trying to make it sticky as well. The issue is that it's not sticky and shows error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null

HTML code:

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
<a href="#career">Careers</a>
<a href="#fellowship">About Us</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunctionForResponsive()">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunctionForSticky()};

// Get the navbar
var navbar = document.getElementById("myTopnav");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. 
Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunctionForSticky() {
    if(window.pageYOffset >= sticky){
    console.log("window.pageYOffset >= sticky");
}
else{
    console.log("Not window.pageYOffset >= sticky");
}
 if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");  
  }
}

/*Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav
when the user clicks on the icon*/

function myFunctionForResponsive() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

If I am taking class instead of id then it's showing the error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

Comment: Where is you script included in the page?

Comment: @connexo In the <head> section at the end, after css link.

Comment: Then you need to wrap code that wants to access the DOM in an event listener that listens on `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: @connexo can you please explain what you said? I am new to this.

Comment: It also helps putting 2 slashes in front of "Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position"

Comment: Added an explanation to my answer below.

Comment: Let me know if anything is unclear. I'll try to help best I can.

Comment: @connexo Hey I have added my issues under your answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code that wants to access the DOM needs to be wrapped in an event listener that listens on `DOMContentLoaded`.

Currently you are trying to access the element with the id `myTopnav` when the browser hasn't parsed the HTML yet, which means your `document.getElementById("myTopnav");` returns `null`. In the next line of code you are trying to read the `offsetTop` property of the `null` that your `document.getElementById("myTopnav")` returned, resulting in `Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null`.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // When the event DOMContentLoaded occurs, it is safe to access the DOM

  // When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
  window.addEventListener('scroll', myFunctionForSticky);

  // Get the navbar
  var navbar = document.getElementById("myTopnav");

  // Get the offset position of the navbar
  var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

  // Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. 
  // Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position

  function myFunctionForSticky() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
      console.log("window.pageYOffset >= sticky");
    } else {
      console.log("Not window.pageYOffset >= sticky");
    }
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
      navbar.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
      navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
  }

  /*Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav
  when the user clicks on the icon*/

  function myFunctionForResponsive() {
    navbar.classList.toggle('responsive');
  }
})
```

Comment: Hey it worked but 2 issues: 1. myFunctionForResponsive() isn't working, I tried to put previous code in this function but still pressing the icon does nothing. 2. I have created my web page in parallax form, so when the background image changes the navigation bar turns grey i.e. it's inaccessible, it's happening on every background image.

Comment: I fixed issue no.2 with z-index but what to do for responsiveness?

Comment: That's a completely different question. The one you've asked should be answered, right?

Answer (score 0):

some DOM element don't have this 'offsetTop' property check the existence before use.
 elements have this property