# Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, navigationbar

I am creating a web page with a responsive and sticky navigation bar. I have created it to be sticky but then responsiveness isn't fully working, i.e. the navigation bar is getting shorter with the hamburger icon but that icon's onClick isn't working.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  window.addEventListener('scroll', myFunctionForSticky);
  var navbar = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

  function myFunctionForSticky() {

    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
      navbar.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
      navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
  }

  function myFunctionForResponsive() {
    navbar.classList.toggle("responsive");
  }

})
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#career">Careers</a>
  <a href="#fellowship">Fellowship 2018</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunctionForResponsive()">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: the scope for those functions is **inside** `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){` therefore, not global, therefore not visible to `onclick` attribute ... use `addEventListner` instead

Comment: @JaromandaX Without 'DOMContentLoaded' only responsiveness was working, navbar wasn't sticky. I followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52532543/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-offsettop-of-null?noredirect=1#comment92005358_52532543 for that.

Comment: yes, and that uses addEventListener, not `<someElement onclick=` - which is why I said use addEventListener, not onclick=

Comment: @JaromandaX can you please explain? I am new to this.

Comment: see how you `window.addEventListener('scroll', myFunctionForSticky);` ... well ... you could do something like `document.querySelector('a.icon').addEventListener('click', myFunctionForResponsive);`

Comment: Oh alright thank you so much!

Comment: alternatively, you could've done `window.myFunctionForResponsive = myFunctionForResponsive` inside that `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){` ... but `addEventListener` is possibly tidier

Comment: Okay, I am just trying and will let you know if still any issue will persist.

Comment: @JaromandaX that worked but whenever I am clicking on the icon the navbar is being opened at the very top of the screen instead of where to it was scrolled.

Comment: so, that's a different problem now