# My Javascript and CSS for a sticky header has not been working

Tags: javascript, html, css

so for a couple hours I have been trying to figure why both CSS sticky and Javascript sticky wont fit with my header. I have looked at all the common issues such as overflow and positioning, but I don't see that being the issue. Any help would be appreciated as this is quite annoying! Before using Javascript I had already tried the position:sticky; position: -webkit-sticky; and top:0; but it hadn't worked either. This is all my code, the javascript is actually in the header of my HTML not in a seperate file.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dropDown').click(function(){
    $('.drop-down').toggleClass('drop-down--active');
  });
});

// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
.navigation
{
    background: #fccfcf;
    height:80px;
}

.content
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}

.post
{
    padding: 10px;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
div.post
{
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-radius: 10px;    
}

.table_center{
  float: right;
  padding: 8px;
  vertical-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
}
.drop-down{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.drop-down__button{
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fee7e7, #fcb6b6);
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}



.drop-down__icon {
    width: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    transition: all 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  
}

.drop-down__menu-box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.drop-down__menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 13px;
    list-style: none;
  
}
.drop-down__menu-box:before{
  content:'';
  background-color: transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #fff;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  top: -15px;
  right: 18px;

}

.drop-down__menu-box:after{
  content:'';
  background-color: transparent;
}

.drop-down__item {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 13px 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #909dc2;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e2e9;
}

.drop-down__item-icon {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    fill: #8995b6;
  
}

.drop-down__item:hover .drop-down__item-icon{
  fill: #3d6def;
}

.drop-down__item:hover{
  color: #3d6def;
}



.drop-down__item:last-of-type{
  border-bottom: 0;
}


.drop-down--active .drop-down__menu-box{
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.drop-down__item:before{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
width: 3px;
height: 28px;
background-color: #3d6def;
left: -13px;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
  display:none;
}

.drop-down__item:hover:before{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pacifico&display=swap" 
rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="basic.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="navigation" id="myHeader">
    <div class="table_center">
       <div class="drop-down">
         <div id="dropDown" class="drop-down__button">
           
<svg version="1.1" class="drop-down__icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="48.625px" height="48.625px" viewBox="0 0 48.625 48.625" style="enable-background:new 0 0 48.625 48.625;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <g>
  <polygon points="35.432,10.815 35.479,11.176 34.938,11.288 34.866,12.057 35.514,12.057 36.376,11.974 36.821,11.445     36.348,11.261 36.089,10.963 35.7,10.333 35.514,9.442 34.783,9.591 34.578,9.905 34.578,10.259 34.93,10.5   " style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></polygon>
  <polygon points="34.809,11.111 34.848,10.629 34.419,10.444 33.819,10.583 33.374,11.297 33.374,11.76 33.893,11.76   " style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></polygon>
  <path d="M22.459,13.158l-0.132,0.34h-0.639v0.33h0.152c0,0,0.009,0.07,0.022,0.162l0.392-0.033l0.245-0.152l0.064-0.307    l0.317-0.027l0.125-0.258l-0.291-0.06L22.459,13.158z" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></path>
  <polygon points="20.812,13.757 20.787,14.08 21.25,14.041 21.298,13.717 21.02,13.498   " style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></polygon>
  <path d="M48.619,24.061c-0.007-0.711-0.043-1.417-0.11-2.112c-0.225-2.317-0.779-4.538-1.609-6.62    c-0.062-0.155-0.119-0.312-0.185-0.465c-1.106-2.613-2.659-4.992-4.56-7.045c-0.125-0.134-0.252-0.266-0.379-0.396    c-0.359-0.373-0.728-0.737-1.11-1.086C36.344,2.402,30.604,0,24.312,0C17.967,0,12.186,2.445,7.852,6.44    C6.842,7.371,5.914,8.387,5.072,9.475C1.896,13.583,0,18.729,0,24.312c0,13.407,10.907,24.313,24.313,24.313    c9.43,0,17.617-5.4,21.647-13.268c0.862-1.682,1.533-3.475,1.985-5.354c0.115-0.477,0.214-0.956,0.3-1.441    c0.245-1.381,0.379-2.801,0.379-4.25C48.625,24.228,48.62,24.145,48.619,24.061z M44.043,14.344l0.141-0.158    c0.185,0.359,0.358,0.724,0.523,1.094l-0.23-0.009l-0.434,0.06V14.344z M40.53,10.102l0.004-1.086    c0.382,0.405,0.75,0.822,1.102,1.254l-0.438,0.652l-1.531-0.014l-0.096-0.319L40.53,10.102z M11.202,7.403V7.362h0.487    l0.042-0.167h0.797v0.348l-0.229,0.306h-1.098L11.202,7.403L11.202,7.403z M11.98,8.488c0,0,0.487-0.083,0.529-0.083    s0,0.486,0,0.486L11.411,8.96l-0.209-0.25L11.98,8.488z M45.592,18.139h-1.779l-1.084-0.807l-1.141,0.111v0.696h-0.361    l-0.39-0.278l-1.976-0.501v-1.28l-2.504,0.195l-0.776,0.417h-0.994L34.1,16.643l-1.207,0.67v1.261l-2.467,1.78l0.205,0.76h0.5    L31,21.838l-0.352,0.129l-0.019,1.892l2.132,2.428h0.928l0.056-0.148h1.668l0.481-0.445h0.946l0.519,0.52l1.41,0.146l-0.187,1.875    l1.565,2.763l-0.824,1.575l0.056,0.742l0.649,0.647v1.784l0.852,1.146v1.482h0.736c-4.096,5.029-10.33,8.25-17.305,8.25    C12.009,46.625,2,36.615,2,24.312c0-3.097,0.636-6.049,1.781-8.732v-0.696l0.798-0.969c0.277-0.523,0.574-1.033,0.891-1.53    l0.036,0.405l-0.926,1.125c-0.287,0.542-0.555,1.096-0.798,1.665v1.27l0.927,0.446v1.765l0.889,1.517l0.723,0.111l0.093-0.52    l-0.853-1.316l-0.167-1.279h0.5l0.211,1.316l1.233,1.799L7.02,21.27l0.784,1.199l1.947,0.482v-0.315l0.779,0.111l-0.074,0.556    l0.612,0.112l0.945,0.258l1.335,1.521l1.705,0.129l0.167,1.391l-1.167,0.816l-0.055,1.242l-0.167,0.76l1.688,2.113l0.129,0.724    c0,0,0.612,0.166,0.687,0.166c0.074,0,1.372,0.983,1.372,0.983v3.819l0.463,0.13l-0.315,1.762l0.779,1.039l-0.144,1.746    l1.029,1.809l1.321,1.154l1.328,0.024l0.13-0.427l-0.976-0.822l0.056-0.408l0.175-0.5l0.037-0.51l-0.66-0.02l-0.333-0.418    l0.548-0.527l0.074-0.398l-0.612-0.175l0.036-0.37l0.872-0.132l1.326-0.637l0.445-0.816l1.391-1.78l-0.316-1.392l0.427-0.741    l1.279,0.039l0.861-0.682l0.278-2.686l0.955-1.213l0.167-0.779l-0.871-0.279l-0.575-0.943l-1.965-0.02l-1.558-0.594l-0.074-1.111    l-0.52-0.909l-1.409-0.021l-0.814-1.278l-0.723-0.353l-0.037,0.39l-1.316,0.078l-0.482-0.671l-1.373-0.279l-1.131,1.307    l-1.78-0.302l-0.129-2.006l-1.299-0.222l0.521-0.984l-0.149-0.565l-1.707,1.141l-1.074-0.131L9.48,21.016l0.234-0.865l0.592-1.091    l1.363-0.69l2.632-0.001l-0.007,0.803l0.946,0.44l-0.075-1.372l0.682-0.686l1.376-0.904l0.094-0.636l1.372-1.428l1.459-0.808    l-0.129-0.106l0.988-0.93l0.362,0.096l0.166,0.208l0.375-0.416l0.092-0.041l-0.411-0.058l-0.417-0.139v-0.4l0.221-0.181h0.487    l0.223,0.098l0.193,0.39l0.236-0.036v-0.034l0.068,0.023l0.684-0.105l0.097-0.334l0.39,0.098v0.362l-0.362,0.249h0.001    l0.053,0.397l1.239,0.382c0,0,0.001,0.005,0.003,0.015l0.285-0.024l0.019-0.537l-0.982-0.447l-0.056-0.258l0.815-0.278l0.036-0.78    l-0.852-0.519l-0.056-1.315l-1.168,0.574h-0.426l0.112-1.001l-1.59-0.375l-0.658,0.497v1.516l-1.183,0.375l-0.474,0.988    l-0.514,0.083v-1.264l-1.112-0.154l-0.556-0.362l-0.224-0.819l1.989-1.164l0.973-0.296l0.098,0.654l0.542-0.028l0.042-0.329    l0.567-0.081l0.01-0.115l-0.244-0.101l-0.056-0.348l0.697-0.059l0.421-0.438l0.023-0.032l0.005,0.002l0.128-0.132l1.465-0.185    l0.648,0.55l-1.699,0.905l2.162,0.51l0.28-0.723h0.945l0.334-0.63l-0.668-0.167V6.212L22.69,5.284l-1.446,0.167l-0.816,0.427    l0.056,1.038l-0.853-0.13L19.5,6.212l0.817-0.742l-1.483-0.074l-0.426,0.129l-0.185,0.5l0.556,0.094l-0.111,0.556l-0.945,0.056    l-0.148,0.37l-1.371,0.038c0,0-0.038-0.778-0.093-0.778c-0.055,0,1.075-0.019,1.075-0.019l0.817-0.798l-0.446-0.223l-0.593,0.576    l-0.984-0.056l-0.593-0.816h-1.261L12.81,6.008h1.206l0.11,0.353l-0.313,0.291l1.335,0.037l0.204,0.482l-1.503-0.056l-0.073-0.371    L12.831,6.54L12.33,6.262l-1.125,0.009C14.888,3.588,19.417,2,24.312,2c5.642,0,10.797,2.109,14.73,5.574l-0.265,0.474    l-1.029,0.403l-0.434,0.471l0.1,0.549l0.531,0.074l0.32,0.8l0.916-0.369l0.151,1.07h-0.276l-0.752-0.111l-0.834,0.14l-0.807,1.14    l-1.154,0.181l-0.167,0.988l0.487,0.115l-0.141,0.635l-1.146-0.23l-1.051,0.23l-0.223,0.585l0.182,1.228l0.617,0.289l1.035-0.006    l0.699-0.063l0.213-0.556l1.092-1.419l0.719,0.147l0.708-0.64l0.132,0.5l1.742,1.175l-0.213,0.286l-0.785-0.042l0.302,0.428    l0.483,0.106l0.566-0.236l-0.012-0.682l0.251-0.126l-0.202-0.214l-1.162-0.648l-0.306-0.861h0.966l0.309,0.306l0.832,0.717    l0.035,0.867l0.862,0.918l0.321-1.258l0.597-0.326l0.112,1.029l0.583,0.64l1.163-0.02c0.225,0.579,0.427,1.168,0.604,1.769    L45.592,18.139z M13.261,11.046l0.584-0.278l0.528,0.126l-0.182,0.709l-0.57,0.181L13.261,11.046z M16.36,12.715v0.459h-1.334    l-0.5-0.139l0.125-0.32l0.641-0.265h0.876v0.265H16.36z M16.974,13.355V13.8l-0.334,0.215l-0.416,0.077c0,0,0-0.667,0-0.737    H16.974z M16.598,13.174v-0.529l0.459,0.418L16.598,13.174z M16.807,14.244v0.433l-0.319,0.32h-0.709l0.111-0.486l0.335-0.029    l0.069-0.167L16.807,14.244z M15.041,13.355h0.737l-0.945,1.321l-0.39-0.209l0.084-0.556L15.041,13.355z M18.059,14.092v0.432    H17.35l-0.194-0.28v-0.402h0.056L18.059,14.092z M17.404,13.498l0.202-0.212l0.341,0.212l-0.273,0.225L17.404,13.498z     M45.954,19.265l0.07-0.082c0.029,0.126,0.06,0.252,0.088,0.38L45.954,19.265z" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></path>
  <path d="M3.782,14.884v0.696c0.243-0.568,0.511-1.122,0.798-1.665L3.782,14.884z" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></path>
 </g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g>
</svg>
         </div>
         
         <div class="drop-down__menu-box">
           <ul class="drop-down__menu">
             <li data-name="profile" class="drop-down__item">Your Profile <svg version="1.1" class="drop-down__item-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 350 350" style="enable-background:new 0 0 350 350;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <path d="M175,171.173c38.914,0,70.463-38.318,70.463-85.586C245.463,38.318,235.105,0,175,0s-70.465,38.318-70.465,85.587   C104.535,132.855,136.084,171.173,175,171.173z"></path>
 <path d="M41.909,301.853C41.897,298.971,41.885,301.041,41.909,301.853L41.909,301.853z"></path>
 <path d="M308.085,304.104C308.123,303.315,308.098,298.63,308.085,304.104L308.085,304.104z"></path>
 <path d="M307.935,298.397c-1.305-82.342-12.059-105.805-94.352-120.657c0,0-11.584,14.761-38.584,14.761   s-38.586-14.761-38.586-14.761c-81.395,14.69-92.803,37.805-94.303,117.982c-0.123,6.547-0.18,6.891-0.202,6.131   c0.005,1.424,0.011,4.058,0.011,8.651c0,0,19.592,39.496,133.08,39.496c113.486,0,133.08-39.496,133.08-39.496   c0-2.951,0.002-5.003,0.005-6.399C308.062,304.575,308.018,303.664,307.935,298.397z"></path>
</g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g>
<g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g>
</svg></li>
             <li data-name="dashboard" class="drop-down__item">Your Dashboard  <svg version="1.1" class="drop-down__item-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="511.626px" height="511.627px" viewBox="0 0 511.626 511.627" style="enable-background:new 0 0 511.626 511.627;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <path d="M491.361,211.274c-13.511-31.599-31.689-58.813-54.529-81.658c-22.839-22.841-50.059-41.017-81.659-54.53   c-31.601-13.513-64.713-20.271-99.359-20.271c-34.644,0-67.762,6.759-99.357,20.271c-31.595,13.518-58.813,31.689-81.653,54.53   c-22.845,22.845-41.018,50.059-54.534,81.658C6.757,242.873,0,275.988,0,310.631c0,49.865,13.418,95.838,40.256,137.903   c3.614,5.52,8.754,8.278,15.417,8.278h400.281c6.66,0,11.8-2.759,15.414-8.278c26.84-42.254,40.258-88.224,40.258-137.903   C511.626,275.988,504.872,242.873,491.361,211.274z M229.973,102.069c7.142-7.139,15.752-10.709,25.84-10.709   c10.089,0,18.699,3.571,25.838,10.709c7.139,7.135,10.711,15.749,10.711,25.837s-3.572,18.699-10.711,25.837   s-15.749,10.709-25.838,10.709c-10.088,0-18.702-3.571-25.84-10.709c-7.135-7.139-10.707-15.749-10.707-25.837   S222.834,109.205,229.973,102.069z M98.929,336.469c-7.138,7.135-15.752,10.715-25.84,10.715c-10.085,0-18.699-3.58-25.837-10.715   c-7.139-7.132-10.705-15.749-10.705-25.838c0-10.088,3.566-18.698,10.705-25.837s15.752-10.708,25.837-10.708   c10.088,0,18.706,3.569,25.84,10.708c7.135,7.139,10.707,15.749,10.707,25.837C109.636,320.72,106.064,329.33,98.929,336.469z    M153.748,208.562c-7.142,7.137-15.752,10.709-25.841,10.709c-10.089,0-18.702-3.576-25.841-10.709   c-7.135-7.135-10.706-15.749-10.706-25.837s3.567-18.699,10.706-25.837c7.142-7.139,15.752-10.709,25.841-10.709   c10.088,0,18.702,3.571,25.841,10.709c7.135,7.139,10.706,15.749,10.706,25.837C164.454,192.81,160.882,201.423,153.748,208.562z    M315.482,210.99l-28.839,109.062c9.524,6.468,16.376,15.126,20.564,25.98c4.182,10.849,4.757,21.984,1.711,33.404   c-3.806,14.657-12.278,25.793-25.413,33.403c-13.135,7.614-27.026,9.521-41.686,5.712c-14.653-3.806-25.791-12.275-33.402-25.41   c-7.611-13.138-9.514-27.027-5.708-41.688c3.044-11.416,9.04-20.79,17.987-28.113c8.944-7.333,19.126-11.468,30.546-12.422   l28.837-109.064c1.331-4.948,4.186-8.711,8.562-11.281c4.381-2.565,8.945-3.184,13.706-1.853c4.764,1.334,8.425,4.139,10.991,8.42   C315.914,201.427,316.625,206.042,315.482,210.99z M357.882,208.562c-7.139-7.135-10.711-15.749-10.711-25.837   s3.572-18.699,10.711-25.837s15.749-10.709,25.838-10.709c10.088,0,18.698,3.571,25.837,10.709s10.712,15.749,10.712,25.837   c0,10.085-3.573,18.699-10.712,25.837c-7.139,7.137-15.749,10.709-25.837,10.709C373.631,219.271,365.021,215.699,357.882,208.562z    M464.374,336.469c-7.139,7.135-15.749,10.715-25.837,10.715c-10.089,0-18.699-3.58-25.838-10.715   c-7.139-7.132-10.708-15.749-10.708-25.838c0-10.088,3.569-18.698,10.708-25.837s15.749-10.708,25.838-10.708   c10.088,0,18.698,3.569,25.837,10.708s10.704,15.749,10.704,25.837C475.078,320.72,471.512,329.33,464.374,336.469z"></path>
</g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g>
</g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g>
</svg></li>
             <li data-name="activity" class="drop-down__item">Recent activity  <svg version="1.1" class="drop-down__item-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="95.103px" height="95.103px" viewBox="0 0 95.103 95.103" style="enable-background:new 0 0 95.103 95.103;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <g id="Layer_1_14_">
  <g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <path d="M47.561,0C25.928,0,8.39,6.393,8.39,14.283v11.72c0,7.891,17.538,14.282,39.171,14.282       c21.632,0,39.17-6.392,39.17-14.282v-11.72C86.731,6.393,69.193,0,47.561,0z"></path>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <path d="M47.561,47.115c-20.654,0-37.682-5.832-39.171-13.227c-0.071,0.353,0,19.355,0,19.355       c0,7.892,17.538,14.283,39.171,14.283c21.632,0,39.17-6.393,39.17-14.283c0,0,0.044-19.003-0.026-19.355       C85.214,41.284,68.214,47.115,47.561,47.115z"></path>
    </g>
   </g>
   <path d="M86.694,61.464c-1.488,7.391-18.479,13.226-39.133,13.226S9.875,68.854,8.386,61.464L8.39,80.82     c0,7.891,17.538,14.282,39.171,14.282c21.632,0,39.17-6.393,39.17-14.282L86.694,61.464z"></path>
  </g>
 </g>
</g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g>
<g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g>
</svg></li>
           </ul>
         </div>
       </div>
</div>
</div>
  
 <div class="content">
    <div class="post">post1</div>
    <div class="post">post2</div>
    <div class="post">post3</div>
    <div class="post">post1</div>
    <div class="post">post2</div>
    <div class="post">post3</div>
    <div class="post">post1</div>
    <div class="post">post2</div>
    <div class="post">post3</div>
    <div class="post">post1</div>
    <div class="post">post2</div>
    <div class="post">post3</div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Sticky seems to work in the snippet but not on my actual webpage.

Answer (score 0):

As I am working on a similar problem, I noticed that the `<script>` is to be placed at the bottom of the code, but still in the `<body>`. I know this may sound weird, but this is what solved my problem. I thought it was supposed to be in the `<head>` but that was not working for me. Here is an example:

```
<html>

<link rel="..." ..... />

    <style>
        Your styles...
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    Your main content...

    <script>
        ...
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me if this fixes your problem. Although this is the way to do it, I would recommend having your JavaScript in a separate file to better organize your code, and to reduce scrolling. Even when you do that, your `<script src="fileName.js"></script>` should still be in the same place. Of course, it is often that an 8-year-old answers incorrectly, so please tell me if this works :)

Comment: This worked for me! thanks for the reply though! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52532543/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-offsettop-of-null

Answer (score 0):

After a while more searching this post appears to answer my question! [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52532543/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-offsettop-of-null)